# Datasets of Historical Locust Attacks

Tags: data-request

Locust swarms are highly mobile and can fly across continents and destroy entire livelihoods in less than six hours, with adult swarms flying about 150km daily. A small (1km2) size swarm (approx. 40 million locusts) can demolish the equivalent amount of food that 35,000 people would eat in a day (Cressman et al., 2016).

Are there any datasets of Locust attacks that happened in the past 25-40 years with lat, long, country, state, area of the land, swarm size, etc.,

Comment: If there is no answer here you can always try to contact the FAO's [Desert Locus Information Service](http://www.fao.org/locusts/en/) whether they have data (that they're willing to share).